# Is there a way to assign numbers to items in a tableView to use in math equations?

Tags: ios, math, tableview

I am making an app that does a lot of mathematical operations.  I want the user to be able to pick an activity from a tableView. I then have an equation that needs to get a number assigned to each activity that the user doesn't see.  So for example if the tableView had items- Running, Jumping, Skipping.  Lets say that each of those activities had the numbers Running= 5, Jumping = 10, Skipping= 15.  The user then selects an activity, lets say running.  The app will then pull the number 5 and use it in an equation, lets say 10*(activity).

Is there anyway to do this?  If you are confused by the question please say something and I will try and clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to assign a value inside the cell.  Remember, you populated the cell with text such as running, jumping and skipping and this data is store someplace.  It's just as easy to maintain the value for each activity along with the cell text, perhaps in a dictionary.

When the user selects an activity, you will get the index path.  Just lookup the value in your data.

If you every add or change the data, it will all be in one place.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSDictionary *dict = [plistDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  NSLog(@"Points: %@", [dict objectForKey:@"points"]);

}
```

Example plist

```
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>label</key>
    <string>Running</string>
    <key>points</key>
    <number>10</number>
  </dict>
  <dict>
    <key>label</key>
    <string>Jumping</string>
    <key>points</key>
    <number>5</number>
  </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Do you know of any good tutorials that deal with this? I am new to programming and this is very overwhelming.

Comment: Just keep programming.  [This page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html) covers many concepts that are key to a good architecture in iOS.

Comment: What is the best way to create the plist, as I have over 800 items... typing each one out in the plist creator in xcode would take forever.

Comment: I have a excel spreadsheet with the name of the activity, and then the number that corresponds to it in a column next to it.  I also found something to do that I can copy them into textEdit with this format

<key>Activity</key><string>bicycling, mountain, uphill, vigorous</string><key>METS</key><integer>14</integer>

Comment: Another option would be create the plist programmatically.  Export a csv file from Excel.  In your app, load the csv file, parse each line, then parse each comma.  Then it should be straight forward to build a plist and save it.  Might be a good solutions if the Excel file will change often.

Comment: You seem to know what you are talking about, so i'll ask another question if you don't mind.  I can't find how to populate the tableView with the data. Any suggestions.  Thanks for all the help

Comment: Use the UITableViewDelegate and add the method - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath.  Here you will create a reusable cell.  Use this cell to set your data; ie cell.textLabel.text = MyDataText;  This is a common question.  Search SO or create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` or store the information in each cell's `tag` property (that is if you're not using it for anything else).  Then simply retrieve this information when you get the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` callback.

It should be noted that storing this information in the cell itself violates the MVC (model-view-controller) design pattern.  While this is not detrimental to the success of your project, it is not considered good coding practice to do so.  You should really try to store the information in some data model you keep on the back-end, and then tie that to your cell in the controller

Comment: +1 for 'It should be noted that storing this information in the cell itself violates the MVC'

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways:

1. set the corresponding value as tag of cell. Like `cell.tag = 5;` for running. When user taps the `cell` retrieve the tag and calculate.
2. Write a method which will return the activity value when you pass the activity label.
   When you tap a cell call a function like: `int valueAct = [self getActivity:cell.textLabel.text];` which will return it's value.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `tag` property of the cell.